# MEAN: unable to update data to DB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

Im trying to update data to mongodb through express, Though my api responds status 200, Im unable to update the values to mongoose, Im using mongoose skin

```
var mongo = require('mongoskin');
var db = mongo.db(config.connectionString, {
    native_parser: true
});
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
db.bind('users');
db.bind('dashboard')

function update(_id, userParam) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(userParam).length; i++) {
        var set = {

            file: userParam[i].file,
            result: userParam[i].result,
            user_id: userParam[i].user_id

        };
        db.dashboard.update({
                _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(_id)
            }, {
                $set: set
            },
            function(err, doc) {
                if (err) deferred.reject(err);
                deferred.resolve();
            });
    };
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

My API

```
{
    "0": {
        "_id": "57396e49a6c36801024021a1",
        "file": "app_static/audio/SampleAudio_0.4mb.mp3",
        "result": "FM",
        "user_id": "57396ded0aef5ee405320dbe"
    },
    "1": {
        "_id": "57396e5ca6c36801024021a2",
        "file": "app_static/audio/SampleAudio_0.7mb.mp3",
        "user_id": "57396ded0aef5ee405320dbe"
    }
}
```

I have have a for loop so that entire api is considered and been to push to mongodb

Please also do suggest any alternative to push entire json to mongodb..

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.dashboard.update` is an asynchronous (a.k.a. non-blocking) function which takes a `callback` as an argument.

You are calling `db.dashboard.update` multiple times (via the `for` loop) **but** inside the `callback` you are rejecting or resolving the *same* `promise`.

This means, that the `then` method of the returned `promise` will be executed when the callback of the very first `db.dashboard.update` is called.

For the rest of the update operations, your `then` function won't be notified.

**SOLUTIONS:**

**1**

Put your asynchronous code inside an [`IIFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) and call your `deferred.resolve` during the last iteration of the loop.

```
function update(_id, userParam) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var length = Object.keys(userParam).length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var set = {

            file: userParam[i].file,
            result: userParam[i].result,
            user_id: userParam[i].user_id

        };

        (function(set, i) { // <------------------------- enclosing everything in an IIFE

            db.dashboard.update({
                    _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(_id)
                }, {
                    $set: set
                },
                function(err, doc) {
                    if (err) {
                        deferred.reject(err);
                    } else if (length - 1 === i) { // <-- checking if this is the last iteration
                        deferred.resolve();
                    }
                });

        })(set, i); // <--------------------------------- sharing set and i with the IIFE scope
    };

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**2**

Use [`async.map`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async#map). (This is the more graceful way of doing it).

```
function update(_id, userParam) {

    var deferred = Q.defer();

    /**
     * Array to contain all the 
     * @type {Array}
     */
    var arrayOfSets = [];

    /**
     * Converting each key-value pair in userParam into an array element
     * and pushing it into arrayOfSets
     */
    for (var i in userParam) {

        arrayOfSets.push({

            file: userParam[i].file,
            result: userParam[i].result,
            user_id: userParam[i].user_id

        });
    }

    /**
     * Executing async.map
     *
     * Parameters:
     * 
     * 1. arrayOfSets - each element will be fed to the function in the 2nd parameter
     *
     * 2. function(item, callback) - in this function do the update operation
     *
     * 3. function(err, result) - in this function resolve or reject the promise
     */
    async.map(arrayOfSets, function(item, callback) {

        db.dashboard.update({
                _id: mongo.helper.toObjectID(_id)
            }, {
                $set: item
            },
            function(err, doc) {
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, null);
                } else {
                    callback(null, doc);
                }
            });

    }, function(err, result) {

        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }

    });

    return deferred.promise;

}
```

---

Also, `else` code should always be enclosed in `else`!

```
function(err, doc) {
    if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    } else { // always enclose in else!
        deferred.resolve();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply...I did try both the logic but did not succeed ..still there mongo is not updating updated values...!

Comment: Could you show what output/result you are getting from the `db.dashboard.update` command?

Comment: when i console db.dashboard.update the result obtained is like this  [Function]

Comment: I meant you should console the output you get from the callback of the `db.dashboard.update` ! :P

Comment: Hi I dint get want you asked...Can you please brief on which call back you wanted...I really appreciate your help

Comment: Place `console.log(err, doc);` within the callbacks, i.e., the functions that look like this `function(err,doc){ ... }`. This will give you the error message if any, and the success message (for the update operation) if any!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112250/discussion-between-coeus-and-blaze-sahlzen).